# Cannot move out of borrowed content trying to deserialize hyper::Request.body()

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, hyper

I'm trying to parse a request body to a strongly typed object using serde_json:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.70
extern crate futures; // 0.1.23
extern crate hyper;   // 0.12.7
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.24

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::{Body, Request};

struct AppError;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct BasicLoginRequest {
    email: String,
    password: String,
}

impl BasicLoginRequest {
    fn from(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<BasicLoginRequest, AppError> {
        let body = req
            .body()
            .fold(Vec::new(), |mut v, chunk| {
                v.extend(&chunk[..]);
                futures::future::ok::<_, hyper::Error>(v)
            }).and_then(move |chunks| {
                let p: BasicLoginRequest = serde_json::from_slice(&chunks).unwrap();
                futures::future::ok(p)
            }).wait();

        Ok(body.unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
20 |           let body = req
   |  ____________________^
21 | |             .body()
   | |___________________^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

From [Cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338659/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-when-unwrapping) I know that this error happens when unwrapping because a value is needed but a reference was supplied.
The error points at `req.body()`; it seems like `req.body()` returns a reference, rather than a value...

The code that tries to handle the body is based on an excerpt copy-pasted from  [Extracting body from Hyper request as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029822/extracting-body-from-hyper-request-as-a-string)

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend reading (at the very least skimming) the documentation for types you use, especially when you are having trouble using them.

For example, [`Request::body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.8/hyper/struct.Request.html#method.body) is defined as:

```
pub fn body(&self) -> &T
```

The very next two methods are

- [`Request::body_mut`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.8/hyper/struct.Request.html#method.body_mut):

  ```
  pub fn body_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T
  ```
- [`Request::into_body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.8/hyper/struct.Request.html#method.into_body):

  ```
  pub fn into_body(self) -> T
  ```

You want to use `into_body`.

I also use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> in my web browser to search for `-> T` once I know that the non-working method returns `-> &T`.